Conky transparency doesn't work
I have an Arch linux with plasma and trying to install conky (AUR).
The problem is all transparent parts are black,here is my config:
background yes
update_interval 1

cpu_avg_samples 1
net_avg_samples 2
temperature_unit celsius

double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes
text_buffer_size 2048

gap_x 40
gap_y 70
minimum_size 300 900
maximum_width 350

own_window yes
own_window_transparent yes 
own_window_type 'desktop'
own_window_argb_visual yes 
own_window_class 'Conky'

own_window yes
own_window_colour 000000
own_window_argb_value 0
own_window_hints undecorated,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below

border_inner_margin 50
border_outer_margin 0
alignment top_right


draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no

override_utf8_locale yes
use_xft yes
xftfont caviar dreams:size=10
xftalpha 0.5
uppercase no


alignment top_right
update_interval 1.0
default_color 000000
default_outline_color 000000
default_shade_color 000000
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 50
own_window yes
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_type desktop
use_xft yes
xftfont sans:size=60
xftalpha 0.2
double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes

